# How to add a single new line at the end of binary tree traversal C++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I wrote a binary search tree class which has a recursive function that prints out all the elements in ascending order.

```
template <typename T>
void BST<T>::printInOrder(BSTNode *t) const
{
    if( t == NULL ){
        return;
    }
    printInOrder( t->left );
    cout << t->element << " ";
    printInOrder( t-> right );
    cout << "\n"; // this is not correct 
}
```

I am trying to add exactly one new line once the largest value is read. How can I do this? In its current state the function just prints n new lines where n is the number of nodes in the tree.

**Note:** This is for a project which stipulates that the newline be called within the function, and that the function itself be recursive.

Comment: _"largest value is **read**"_ -- do you mean written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Newline added within the function
- Function must be recursive

Odd requirements, but given that, this is an approach:

```
template <typename T>
void BST<T>::printInOrder(BSTNode *t, bool addNewline) const
{
    if( t == NULL ){
        return;
    }
    printInOrder( t->left, false );
    cout << t->element << " ";
    printInOrder( t-> right, false );
    if( addNewLine )
        cout << "\n";
}

// ...somewhere else...
bst.printInOrder(node, true);
```

But really, you should use two functions, or add the newline yourself:

```
bst.printInOrder(node);
cout << "\n";
```

Comment: Maybe so, but still this is a nice solution. Thanks for the help!